# Friends requests on external website not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, request

I can't get the request script to work on an external website. I used the same example given in JS SDK Docs any workaround guys?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Edit: by not working I mean that the dialog box appear but the requests are not sent to recipents I tested that with help of many friends

Comment: Define "not working". Right now your question is extraordinarily unhelpful.

Comment: you are right just edited my question

Answer (score 4):

That is by intent:

> User to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: I find this facebook concept silly, because you can send inbox messages to a user, to me that's more of a risk than a silly little notification

Answer (score 2):

As said by Hendrik in other answer this is desired behavior.

Couple of noted through:

- By Canvas Apps Facebook consider every app that have Canvas URL defined. So if application have Canvas URL requests will work from Site using that application (accepting request will work that same way, redirecting to application canvas)
- Once user accepting request (landing to application canvas) Facebook add `request_ids` parameter to Canvas URL, so you can easily redirect user to desired page (since Requests have ability to store additional data, it should be easy to store some sort of instructions/data you can rely on deciding where to redirect).

Comment: This would be prohibited from December 5th. Link: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/ Games on Facebook.com and mobile must not share the same app ID with desktop web games off of Facebook.com. You must not use Canvas apps to promote or link to game sites off of Facebook